# Help with view on multiple pages

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I experimented for a few hours with drupal (tried contextual filters) and searched across the internet, but couldn't find a solution for my problem. (I'm not a "drupal engineer", so maybe it's very easy to solve this problem, but I couldn't).

I have view that I want to use on multiple pages on our drupal site. 
If the user browses to http://www.mywebsite.com/######, is it possible to display that view, but showing only nodes that contain "######" in a specific field in the content type displayed by that view?

edit: when ####### isn't found in that field (if 'ts available in the content type), of course it should not show the view. When ######### isn't provided (http://www.mywebsite.com/), it should display the view without te filter....

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify if this is a block view or a page view.

If it's a page view, you have to use `/something/%` as your path.

1) Add your field in question as a contextual filter. (I used title as an example)

2) Use *Provide a default value*

- *Raw Value from URL*
- Path is 1 assuming its `yourwebsite.com/####`. Path is 2 if `yourwebsite.com/something/####`

[image]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7f7IR.png is what i have now, but that doesn't work. I Didn't create that view, but i don't think a page was created for it. So i think it's a block view?

Comment: @user3122986 Well.. it should've worked, did you use the field in question as your contextual filter? Did you clear the cache?

Comment: Ssweat I think that the filter partially works. I've enabled the functionality to rewrite the page title and that's ok, but no content is displayed when using a filter....